# how to display contents of json object via make_response

Tags: python, json, flask

i send a json object to the webservice and i am trying to get that json object as follows:

```
@app.route("/insecticidesSpecifications/<string:parameters>", methods=['GET'] )
def insecticidesSpecifications(parameters):
    logger.debug(make_response(parameters,200).get_data)
```

the result is as shown below. i can not see the contents of the json object.
please let me know how to get the contents of the json object correctly.

**output**:

```
 INFO:werkzeug: - - [02/Aug/2021 14:59:16] "OPTIONS /insecticidesSpecifications/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 200 -
DEBUG:root:<bound method BaseResponse.get_data of <Response 15 bytes [200 OK]>>
INFO:werkzeug: - - [02/Aug/2021 14:59:16] "GET /insecticidesSpecifications/[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_data` is a method, that you need to call:

```
@app.route("/insecticidesSpecifications/<string:parameters>", methods=['GET'] )
def insecticidesSpecifications(parameters):
    response = make_response(parameters,200)
    logger.debug(response.get_data())
```

The use of the `response` variable is not needed, but it is easier to read like this

Comment: i used it as you suggested but the results i get is: <bound method BaseResponse.get_data of <Response 18 bytes [200 OK]>>

Comment: You still didn't include the `()` after `get_data`. I called with parameters `asdf`. With `response.get_data()` the result is `b'asdf'`. With `response.get_data` the result is `<bound method Response.get_data of <Response 4 bytes [200 OK]>>`